# How to use an IPageFilter on razor page with no model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Is there a way to apply an `IPageFilter` on a razor page which does not have a model?

The page is a simple get request.

```
@page
@{
    @functions{

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Just want to know If it's possible to add a simple i.e. `Authorize` attribute (or any `IPageFilter` attributes) in the above page. As the attributes work on following page when there exist a child class of `PageModel`.

```
@{
    @functions
    {
        [Authorize]
        public class TestModel : PageModel
        {
            public void OnGet()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a page application model convention to add one. There’s an AddFilter convention extension that accepts a func